# React / NextJS Audio Player Buttons not working after introducing a State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm customizing an Audio Player component within a NextJs application. The basis for this is the ReactAudioPlayer package. `Import Next/Audio` wouldn't work and using solely `<Audio>` did not work with props.

The player generally behaves as intended, but my attempt to introduce two custom Buttons via a state assignment - leads to the newly created Play / Pause buttons not triggering the player to play our pause songs.  I have created a simple state:

```
    function AudioPlayer(this: any, props: any) {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  const handlePlay = () => setIsPlaying(true);
  const handlePause = () => setIsPlaying(false);
```

And embedded both play and pause values into the ReactAudioPlayer component:

```
   <ReactAudioPlayer
          src={props.trackLink}
          controls={false}
          onPlay={() => handlePlay()}
          onPause={() => handlePause()}
          autoPlay={true}
        />
        {isPlaying ? (
          <button
            className="group h-12 w-12 rounded-full border-white bg-transparent duration-100 ease-in hover:bg-white"
            onClick={handlePause}
          >
            <svg
              width="10px"
              height="14px"
              viewBox="0 0 10 14"
              className="m-auto group-hover:invert"
            >
              <g
                id="Icon-Export"
                stroke="none"
                strokeWidth="1"
                fill="none"
                fillRule="evenodd" >
                
            </svg>
          </button>
        ) : (
          <button
            className="group h-12 w-12 rounded-full border-white bg-transparent duration-100 ease-in hover:bg-white"
            onClick={handlePlay}
          >
            <svg
              width="10px"
              height="14px"
              viewBox="0 0 10 14"
              className="m-auto group-hover:invert"
            >
              <g
                id="Icon-Export"
                stroke="none"
                strokeWidth="1"
                fill="none"
                fillRule="evenodd"
              >
              </g>
            </svg>
          </button>
```

The button themselves works as intended, switching between the Play and Pause state visually, **but no audio track is being played** ( or paused ). Since Audio Tracks are working and playing when Autoplay is activated, the respective source prop is passed correctly and missing audio files are **not** a possible error cause.

Where is my mistake in getting the custom buttons to work?

Comment: Your `isPlaying` is not connected in any way with `ReactAudioPlayer`

Comment: Can you elaborate further please?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. I kind of look like you were creating this component again by accident

Answer (score 1):

The issue actually is not with your code, Its about how react works. Every `setState` make react to do a re-render. In this case The `setIsPlaying` call causes re-rendering and initialises a new instance of Audio every time the component re-renders, you'll have to call useRef to persist the Audio instance between each render.  This is how you can do it even without the AudioPlayer lib.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function AudioPlayer() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3';

  const audioRef = useRef(new Audio(url));

  const play = () => {
    setPlaying(true);
    audioRef.current.play();
  };

  const pause = () => {
    setPlaying(false);
    audioRef.current.pause();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'none',
        }}
        onClick={playing ? pause : play}
      >
        {playing ? 'Pause' : 'Play'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AudioPlayer;
```